# Open new Chrome tab into an existing window from terminal?

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, alias

I have created the alias `alias chrome="google-chrome &"` but even if Chrome is already open it still opens a new window.
Is there anyway to just create a new tab in the existing window if it's already open?

Answer (score 0):

This alias works for me in 18.04:

```
alias gct='wmctrl -a " - Google Chrome" && sleep 0.5 && xdotool key ctrl+t'
```

- It requires you to have *wmctrl* and *xdotool* installed. Both are in the software center.
- `wmctrl -a " - Google Chrome"` will raise a window into focus if that window has `- Google Chrome` in its window title. (You can see that for yourself by running `wmctrl -l` or `wmctrl -lx`.)
- `xdotool key ctrl+t` simply issues the same key sequence that you would issue to open a new tab in Google Chrome.

---

You may want to convert the alias into a script which does something if Google Chrome *isn't* running and then alias that script or even assign a shortcut key to it so you don't need to use the terminal for this purpose.